# Can we read a value of certain key in appsettings section and modify the other appsettings key value in transform web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web.config-transform

Like in the below code:

```
<add key="DeployEnv" value="Test"/> --one value in appsettings
```

modify the following one in transform config file by reading the value of above key in transform config file:

```
<add key="DatabaseConnstring" value="dbcon-test"/>
```

Comment: <add key="DeployEnv" value="Test"/>

Comment: modify the below one  by reading the value of above key in transform config file

Comment: <add key="DBconnstring" value="dbconn-test"/>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].